# how to manage high ram usage of an MPI app

Tags: ram

I have an SSD and 8 gigs of ram but i am running an app that runs on 30 gigs on a workstation. So far it ran fine but at the very end of a process it started to trash and i had to shut down. How can i manage SSD swapping so it does not happen but still runs "ok" (4 core cpu)?

SSD: Patriot Burst 500GB

No windows and i only use firefox ocassionally (1-4 tabs).

i dont mind my laptop being lightly choppy as long as i can watch videos. The process is running and works fine at the moment. But it started to thrash at the end which will be in several hours from now.

```
vm.Swappiness = 60
```

before end:

```
Mem: total 7.7GB used 5.7GB free 1GB shared 12M buff/cache 947M available 1.6GB

Swap: total 31GB used 532M free 31GB
```

at end:

```
Mem: Total 7,7GB used 7.1GB free 123M shared 11M buff/cache 467M available 303M

Swap: total 31GB used 2.1GB free 29GB

/swapfile none     swap 0 sw 0

/dev/sda1 EFI fat32 /boot/efi 512.00MiB used 9.92 MiB unused 502.08 MiB boot, esp

/dev/sda2 (noname) ext4 "/" 446.63 GiB used 304.03 GiB unused 142.60 GiB noflags
```

Comment: I think you meant "thrash". Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. What brand SSD? Do you have Windows installed also? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema so i updated as requested.

Comment: When you say thrash, do you mean lots of disk I/O? I suspect that you need more RAM and more swap. Please show me the **full** `free -h` after you've been running for a while. Also show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and a screenshot of `gparted`. What version Ubuntu?

Comment: it stopped unfortunately. Swap was full and ram was on 300mb left. grep shows zeros and none now. Gparted shows two partitions sda1 (efi) and sda2 (170GB unused). I mean it ran out of memory and stopped working because swap was full.

Comment: It stopped when i started firefox btw. So if i create a swap of 16 counts 2GB each i would technically have enough but significantly reduce life of my ssd.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you're probably needing more RAM and more swap. Modern SSD's don't have a life issue with swap. Increase your swap to at least 8G, and if that doesn't help by itself, we'll try a different vm.swappiness value. You didn't answer my other requests. Report back.

Comment: So i increased it at ~32GB and will keep my memory in check. I will send all data you requested at the same time tmr (so we can see exact data when it stopped working, and if swap gets full again), is that ok?

Comment: I recommended an 8G swap. No need to over do it. Report back.

Comment: Status please. Did more swap solve/improve your situation? How much swap did you settle on?

Comment: @heynnema Because the second restart made the whole process to repeat itself not just a part of it it took longer time. I have nice data for you. Uploading now.

Comment: @heynnema if i were to start firefox now it would go to swap or push something in swap. That isnt ideal but at least now it wont stop responding.

Comment: If the last three lines are something kinda out of `/etc/fstab`, then the statement `/swapfile none     swap 0 sw 0` is wrong. Also, as I mentioned before, 32G swap is way excessive. 8G would probably work fine. Still consider more RAM.

Comment: Thanks tho. It finished! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

```
Mem 7.7GB Available 517MB
Swap 2 GB Available 1.4 GB
```

Do to the use of an application that requires significant resources, I recommend more RAM and more swap.

Add RAM in matched pairs, to take advantage of memory interleaving. So if you've got one 8G DIMM now, add another 8G DIMM. If you've got two 4G DIMMs, then replace them with two 8G DIMMs.

I recommend trying a 8G swap for now. We can adjust it later. We can also adjust vm.swappiness later if it's determined to require adjustment.